# How to use a template without a shadowRoot?

Tags: polymer

I expected one of the two togglePanels() to work but they do not?

```
<template>
    <core-drawer-panel forceNarrow>
    </core-drawer-panel>
</template>

<script>
    var t = document.querySelector('template');
    t.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel()
    t.shadowRoot.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel()
</script>
```

Also note that in my console it says #document-fragment instead of #shadowRoot because I can not wrap it in a polymer element, so that the other js frameworks do not break.

[image: template]

EDIT: Turns out I needed to do `document.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel()` but that brings me to the problem core-drawer-panel is not ready yet. Will ask in a other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per default `<template>` is **not** inserted into the your visible DOM. This is why you don't see anything within your page.

You should do append the `template` first and then wait for the page is loaded. Just do it like this:

```
<div id="insertTemplateHere">
  <template>
    <core-drawer-panel forceNarrow></core-drawer-panel>
  </template>
</div>

<script>
// with jQuery: wait until page is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  // grab the element, where you want to insert the template
  var page = document.querySelector('#insertTemplateHere');

  // grab the template itself and read the whole content into `clone`
  var template = document.querySelector('template');
  var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);

  // append the content into the previously grabbed element
  page.appendChild(clone);

  // now use the element within the template
  template.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel();

  // you don't need the shadowRoot, since you don't have any
  // template.shadowRoot.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel();
});

// native: wait until page is ready (works on ~90% of all global browsers used)
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // grab the element, where you want to insert the template
  var page = document.querySelector('#insertTemplateHere');

  // grab the template itself and read the whole content into `clone`
  var template = document.querySelector('template');
  var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);

  // append the content into the previously grabbed element
  page.appendChild(clone);

  // now use the element within the template
  template.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel();

  // you don't need the shadowRoot, since you don't have any
  // template.shadowRoot.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel();
});
</script>
```

Please note: There is **no** isolation of the content of the `<template>`. Only the `<core-drawer-panel>` brings his own shadow root.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the issue is that you aren't waiting for the polymer-ready event, so the template hadn't yet been expanded.

```
<script>
  // need to wait for initialization to complete
  document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
    var t = document.querySelector('template');
    t.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel()
    t.shadowRoot.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel()
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I would like to use a template outside polymer so the other js frameworks do not break :) I can not wrap it inside a polymer element can only use a vanilla template with polymer elements inside.

Comment: And it seems you are right :) because document.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel() only works after the page is loaded. How can I watch for the ready event outside polymer?

Comment: document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {/* your code here */});