# polymer-ready event is not ready yet?

Tags: polymer

When I try document.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel() in the console it works but when I do the following core-drawer-panel is not ready yet?

```
<template>
    <core-drawer-panel forceNarrow>
    </core-drawer-panel>
</template>

<script>
        document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
            document.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel()
            console.log('polymer-ready');
        });
</script>
```

Note that I can not wrap it in a polymer element due to issues with other js frameworks.

Comment: You should first insert the template into your page. A `<template>` is just a place where some content is, but the content is **not** appended into the page itself, neither are there any resources (like images) requested. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899319/how-to-use-a-template-without-a-shadowroot/26933548#26933548

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
var template = document.querySelector('template');
template.addEventListener('template-bound', function () {
    //code
});
```

with your element inside a template you need to look for template to be ready not polymer.

Comment: Yes, working :D Can you commit this to the polymer documentation please?

Comment: i am not sure but i think i got this gem from the section on auto binding templates on polymer-project.org

Comment: Ok now I see it at the bottom :) https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html

Comment: @jimidough10 This doesn't seem to work in polymer 1.0 and link to docs is broken. Do you know how to do this currently? It would be extremely useful to me.

Comment: The event in polymer 1.0 is "dom-change"